# Calling Procedure or function in the package

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have Created a Package and procedure and functions within.
I have a small doubt.
If I have created procedure name employee_dtls in the package and at the same time
employee_dtls procedure as an independent object in the schema.

But i want to call the independent procedure employee_dtls inside my package but when I am trying to call
the procedure within the package is getting executed an independent one is not being called.

I assume since the name of both the procedures are the same it is calling the procedure inside the package.

Please help what can I do in this case?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment or a real system?  I am very hard-pressed to imagine a situation in a real system where you would really want a standalone procedure with the same name as a procedure in a package.  If it's a homework assignment, just use the fully qualified object name.  If it's a real system, take a step back and reassess your naming standards.

Comment: @JustinCave Thank you for your reply. 
This was just for checking, how can we achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

What can you do? Qualify procedure name (as Justin commented). Here's how (read comments within code):

Standalone procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test is
  2  begin
  3    dbms_output.put_line('...standalone P_TEST procedure');
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.
```

Packaged procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace package pkg_test is
  2    procedure p_test;
  3    procedure p_run;
  4  end;
  5  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pkg_test is
  2    procedure p_test is
  3    begin
  4      dbms_output.put_line('...packaged P_TEST procedure');
  5    end;
  6
  7
  8    procedure p_run is
  9    begin
 10      dbms_output.put_line('calling P_TEST');
 11      p_test;           -- no qualifier - runs the packaged procedure (that's what you have now)
 12
 13      dbms_output.put_line('calling SCOTT.P_TEST');
 14      scott.p_test;     -- procedure name preceded by owner name - runs the standalone procedure
 15
 16      dbms_output.put_line('calling PKG_TEST.P_TEST');
 17      pkg_test.p_test;  -- procedur ename preceded by package name - runs the packaged procedure
 18    end;
 19  end;
 20  /

Package body created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> exec pkg_test.p_run;
calling P_TEST
...packaged P_TEST procedure
calling SCOTT.P_TEST
...standalone P_TEST procedure
calling PKG_TEST.P_TEST
...packaged P_TEST procedure

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```